# MS Access using function as criteria in select query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a report setup with a record source of one of my select queries.

What I want to do is on my form have a series of buttons for each manager that when pressed opens the report with the select query criteria being set to the manager name.

On button press I have:

```
Dim MgrName As String
MgrName = "Smith"
Call Testfunction (MgrName)
DoCmd.OpenReport "R_Test_Logout_10", acViewReport
```

Also:

```
Public Function TestFunction(MgrName)
    If MgrName = "Smith" Then
        TestFunction = "Smith, Joe"
    End If
End Function
```

When I try to put `TestFunction` in the criteria in the select query I either get an error for wrong number of arguments or if I put it in as:

```
TestFunction (MgrName)
```

...it auto inserts quotes to:

```
TestFunction ("MgrName")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `WhereCondition` argument for the [`DoCmd.OpenReport`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.openreport) method.

For example, you could define a function such as:

```
Function OpenMyReport(strMgr As String)
    DoCmd.OpenReport "R_Test_Logout_10", acViewReport, , "Manager = '" & strMgr & "'"
End Function
```

(Assuming that the Record Source for your report contains a field called `Manager`)

And then call the above function from the event handler for the `On Click` event for each button, e.g.:

```
Private Sub MyButton_Click()
    OpenMyReport "Smith, Joe"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I tried your solution and it did work but I left out one detail which appears important.  I can open the report that way without problems with a single report but my end goal is opening a report which contains 4 sub reports (all with the same manager criteria).

Comment: @Timeetyo In that case you would link the Child `Manager` field within each subreport to the Master `Manager` field within the main report. Filtering the Master field would then automatically filter the Child field.